# Given the definition of $\leq$, prove $((a \leq b) \implies (b \leq a)) \implies (a = b)$.

Tags: logic, induction

**Given the definition of $\leq$, prove $((a \leq b) \implies (b \leq a)) \implies (a = b)$.**

**$\leq$ is defined as:** 

$a \leq$ b := 
Case $a=0: True$ 
Case $a=Succ(p)$: 
....Case $b=0: False$ 
....Case $b=Succ(q): p \leq q$

(*Succ(n) means the successor of n which is (n+1))

**Prove** $((a \leq b) \implies (b \leq a)) \implies (a = b)$

Comment: Implication is not associative. You need to write brakets since $(x \to y) \to z$ and $x \to (y \to z)$ are not equivalent.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\left(a\le b\;\wedge\;b\le a\right)\implies a=b\;\;?$

Comment: @drhab The definition is given in the description as $a \leq b :=$ states. Successor is self-explanatory so I omitted. I will add it on the description. I will put brackets on the prove statement as well.

Comment: @Joanpemo the problem statement is given like the description, but yeah what I want to try is pretty much what you wrote.

Comment: @drhab btw this is an induction problem.

Comment: @Crostul ok brackets added.

Comment: Induction? On what?

Comment: The statement as it stands is simply false: for any $a,b$ such that $b \le a$, $(a \leq b) \implies (b \leq a)$ is true, but $a=b$ can be false.

Comment: In what set are you working that you use $n+1$? Things have improved, but not everything is clear.

Comment: @TonyK I did induction by taking cases but failed at that point as well. To be specific, the case where $a=0$ and $b=Succ(q)$ fails because it becomes $False \implies True \implies False$ which is $False$. I was wondering whether there is any other way.

Comment: Any other way? To prove a false statement? I hope not!

Comment: @drhab Hmm.. Actually this is from Formal Logic for Computer Science. Maybe the concept of induction is a bit different.... :(

Comment: Perhaps you have bracketed it wrong? $(a \leq b) \implies ((b \leq a) \implies (a = b))$ is true.

Comment: @TonyK That statement works eh.. There was no brackets given in the problem, so maybe there was a mistake in problem.

Comment: So you just took a guess? What a waste of time for everybody concerned!

Comment: @TonyK I'll ask the problem author about this matter and show him your alternative statement. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @TonyK Well, people were complaining about it, so I put the brackets in the place where it seems to make minimal change :/

Comment: But that was _after_ we told you that the position of the brackets makes a difference. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

By reductio ad absurdum: supose $\;a\neq b\;$ and without resticting generality, supose $\;a<b\;$ . But then $\;b\rlap{\,\;/}< a\;$ ,which contradicts the premise.

Or using the usual definition of inequality:

$$a<b\implies b-a>0\implies a-b=-(b-a)<0\implies b\rlap{\;\,/}<a\;\;\text{-- contradiction}$$

Comment: You have just proved a false statement $-$ see my comment to the OP. Your mistake is when you say "without restricting generality": $(a \leq b) \implies (b \leq a)$ is not symmetrical in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you. Read the comments: the asker said he wants to try what I wrote before he added parentheses, and what I wrote is conjunction: $\;\left(a\le b\,\wedge\,b\le a\right)\implies a=b\;$ . In this case I don't think there's a problem.

Comment: @Joanpemo Sorry, I intuitively thought it might have no different, but from the way discussion went it seems it makes the problem different. But considering that there is a chance the question itself has a problem, I will tell the question author about this alternative as well. Thank you :)